# Mistake in autoResizingMask

Tags: iphone, viewdidload, autoresizingmask

i have implemented a small viewDidLoad() to show an Picture with autoresizing,
but it doesn't work, could please someone help me and say what is the mistake in
this code in line 3 and 4????

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imageView.frame = self.view.frame;
    imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

i hope someone could help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If im not mistaken you should do it the following way:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight );
```

The way you do it, you override the autoresizingMask.